# How to fix InputMismatchException

Tags: java, error-handling, io

So i have this code:

```
protected void giveNr(Scanner sc) {
    //variable to keep the input
    int input = 0;
    do {
      System.out.println("Please give a number between: " + MIN + " and " + MAX);
      //get the input
      input = sc.nextInt();
    } while(input < MIN || input > MAX);
}
```

If the human inputs sth thats not an integer, say a letter or a string, the program crashes and gives the error, `InputMismatchException`. How can I fix it, so that when a wrong type of input is entered, the human is asked again for the input(and the program does not crash?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch the `InputMismatchException`, print an error message telling the user what went wrong, and go around the loop again:

```
int input = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Please give a number between: " + MIN + " and " + MAX);
    try {
        input = sc.nextInt();
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("That was not a number.  Please try again.");
        input = MIN - 1; // guarantee we go around the loop again
    }
while (input < MIN || input > MAX)
```